# Sum of column inside a array in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to MongoDB and trying to find the sum of device_status out of 
   device_execution array for a given serial number.e.g serial number 
   ELMESR0719PXN6 has two device status respectively 200 and 400 at a given 
   time.After each 5 minutes device status keep coming and we are storing it.So 
   we want to add the sum of status 200 or 400 per serial number.Below is the 
   document which contains all the details :

Output should be like below :

```
Serial number     Device_status     Sum
ELMESR0719PXN6    200               5
                  400               5
```

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e57b3376c8b9aabd5312840"),
        "ve_serial_number" : "ELMESR0719PXN6",
        "ve_type" : "eVE",
        "start_ts" : "2020-02-19T00:00:00.000+00:00",
        "end_ts" : "2020-02-19T23:59:59.999+00:00",
        "device_execution" : [
                {
                        "execution_time" : "2020-02-19T00:00:00.000+00:00",
                        "device_status" : {
                                "200" : 4,
                                "400" : 2
                        }
                },
                {
                        "execution_time" : "2020-02-19T00:02:00.000+00:00",
                        "device_status" : {
                                "200" : 1,
                                "400" : 3
                        }
                }
        ]
}
```

Can you please help me in finding the solution?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one gives desired result:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $unwind: "$device_execution" },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: "$ve_serial_number",
         "400": { $sum: "$device_execution.device_status.400" },
         "200": { $sum: "$device_execution.device_status.200" }
      }
   }
])
```

Result:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "ELMESR0719PXN6", 
    "200" : 5.0, 
    "400" : 5.0
}
```

The format is not the final one, this I leave up to you.

Comment: Can I add the "execution_time" check into the above query so that based on time gap I can find the total sum of respones for a given serial no?

Comment: Yes, of course. Would be _id: `_id: { ve_serial_number: "$ve_serial_number", execution_time: "$execution_time" }`

Comment: Thanks Wernfried for your quick answer.now its showing execution time also but I think I put my question wrongly.actually based on execution time,I want to show the serial nos with sum of responses.Suppose if a user wants to show the details for a selected execution time (between 2 pm and 3 pm how many serial nos are there with total no. of responses).Sorry for asking too many questions!

Comment: Add like `{$match: {$gte: ["$start_ts", "2020-02-19T02:00:00.000+00:00"]}}` (plus upper bound) to the pipeline

Comment: Thanks a lot!I changed it bit and it worked for me.I wanted execution_time as condition :)
```
db.mft_stats.aggregate([
   { $unwind: "$device_execution" },
   {$match: {"device_execution.execution_time" : {$gte: "2020-02-19T00:00:00.000+00:00",$lte : "2020-02-19T02:00:00.000+00:00"}}},    
   {
      $group: {
         _id: { ve_serial_number: "$ve_serial_number" },
         "400": { $sum: "$device_execution.device_status.400" },
         "200": { $sum: "$device_execution.device_status.200" }
      }
   }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by using [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) operator for "device_execution" field

Then you can just [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) them by "ve_serial_number" and "device_status" and sum them up.

Comment: `device_status` is not an array, thus `$unwind` make no sense on it.